# linux command to view/list changes made to the file last time

Tags: c++, linux, unix

I know there is command to find recently modified files in Linux **but is there way to view/list changes made to the file last time?**

for example: i have existing file(File1.cpp) of 1000 lines of code in it. I added few lines of code at line 10, 100, 200 and saved it. Next day I want to check what is modified in File1.cpp from terminal.

Comment: I removed the Vim tag because it was irrelevant.

Comment: diff with backup file